# Scrape information with form submit using Phantom

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs

I want to do web scraping of [this site](http://data.un.org/Data.aspx?q=population&d=PopDiv&f=variableID%3A12).
I have seen that the APIs are available but, as suggested by *duraid* in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49705059/download-data-from-undata-of-onu/49709369#49709369), it is not advisable to use them.

So I tried to use `Node.js` and [`Phantom.js`](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj0_P6146jaAhXsKsAKHfhCAcMQFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphantomjs.org%2F&usg=AOvVaw06wt7iUuvR9VtVXUxcnV34) with [`Phantom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom).

This is my code:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

// object of methods
var methods = {};
var loadInProgress = false;
var url = 'http://data.un.org/Data.aspx?q=population&d=PopDiv&f=variableID%3A12';

methods.download = async function(req, res) {
    const instance = await phantom.create();
    const page = await instance.createPage();

    await page.on('onResourceRequested', function(requestData) {
        console.info('Requesting', requestData.url);
    });
    await page.on('onConsoleMessage', function(msg) {
        console.info(msg);
    });
    await page.on('onLoadStarted', function() {
        loadInProgress = true;
        console.log('Load started...');
    });
    await page.on('onLoadFinished', function() {
        loadInProgress = false;
        console.log('Load end');
    });

    const status = await page.open(url);
    console.log('STATUS:', status);

    const content = await page.property('content');
    console.log('CONTENT:', content);

    // submit
    await page.evaluate(function() {
        document.getElementById('crID%3a250').value = 'crID%3a250'; // France
        document.getElementById('timeID%3a79').value = 'timeID%3a79'; // 2015
        document.getElementById('varID%3a2').value = 'varID%3a2'; // Medium
        document.getElementById('ctl00_main_filters_anchorApplyBottom').submit(); // submit button
    });

    var result = await page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.querySelectorAll('html')[0].outerHTML; 
    });
    console.log('RESULT:', result);

    await instance.exit();
};

module.exports = methods;
```

(How can they select more countries and more years?)

I tried to select *France* as **Country or Area**, *2015* as a **Year** and *medium* as a **Variants**.

So `crID%3a250` is *id* of element:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="crID%3a250" value="crID%3a250" name="France" />
<label for="crID%3a250">France</label><br />
```

`timeID%3a79` is *id* of element:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="timeID%3a79" value="timeID%3a79" name="2015" />
<label for="timeID%3a79">2015</label><br />
```

`varID%3a2` is *id* of element:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="varID%3a2" value="varID%3a2" name="Medium" />
<label for="varID%3a2">Medium</label><br />
```

And then `ctl00_main_filters_anchorApplyBottom` is *id* of button element:

```
<div class="All">
    <img src="_Images/IconUpdateResults.png" alt="Update" width="11px" height="11px" title="Apply filters" />&nbsp;<a href="javascript:;" id="ctl00_main_filters_anchorApplyBottom" title="Apply filters" onclick="ApplyFilters(SendFilterRequest);">Apply Filters</a>
</div>
```

But what I got is the web page itself (in HTML), not the data that interest me.
So it's as if I had not selected any parameters. Why?

---

## EDIT 1

After the advice of @Vaviloff I tried to change the code but without success.
My server-side language is Node.js.

Using `Phantom` I modified the code like this:

```
methods.download = async function(req, res) {
    const instance = await phantom.create();
    const page = await instance.createPage();

    await page.on('onResourceRequested', function(requestData) {
        console.log('Requesting', requestData.url);
    });
    await page.on('onConsoleMessage', function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    });

    const status = await page.open(url);
    console.log('\n\nSTATUS:', status);

    // submit
    await page.evaluate(function() {
        var countries = {
            'Albania': 'crID%3a8',
            'Austria': 'crID%3a40',
            'Belgium': 'crID%3a56',
            'Bulgaria': 'crID%3a100',
            'Croatia': 'crID%3a191',
            'Cyprus': 'crID%3a196',
            'Denmark': 'crID%3a208',
            'Estonia': 'crID%3a233',
            'Finland': 'crID%3a246',
            'France': 'crID%3a250',
            'Germany': 'crID%3a276',
            'Greece': 'crID%3a300',
            'Iceland': 'crID%3a352',
            'Ireland': 'crID%3a372',
            'Italy': 'crID%3a380',
            'Latvia': 'crID%3a428',
            'Netherlands': 'crID%3a528',
            'Norway': 'crID%3a578',
            'Poland': 'crID%3a616',
            'Portugal': 'crID%3a620',
            'Romania': 'crID%3a642',
            'Slovakia': 'crID%3a703',
            'Slovenia': 'crID%3a705',
            'Spain': 'crID%3a724',
            'Sweden': 'crID%3a752',
            'Switzerland': 'crID%3a756',
            'United Kingdom': 'crID%3a826'
        };
        // 2018 - 1980
        var years = ['timeID%3a83', 'timeID%3a82', 'timeID%3a81', 'timeID%3a79', 'timeID%3a78', 'timeID%3a77', 'timeID%3a76', 'timeID%3a75', 'timeID%3a73', 'timeID%3a72', 'timeID%3a71', 'timeID%3a70', 'timeID%3a69', 'timeID%3a67', 'timeID%3a66', 'timeID%3a65', 'timeID%3a64', 'timeID%3a63', 'timeID%3a61', 'timeID%3a60', 'timeID%3a59', 'timeID%3a58', 'timeID%3a57', 'timeID%3a55', 'timeID%3a54', 'timeID%3a53', 'timeID%3a52', 'timeID%3a51', 'timeID%3a49', 'timeID%3a48', 'timeID%3a47', 'timeID%3a46', 'timeID%3a45', 'timeID%3a43', 'timeID%3a42', 'timeID%3a41', 'timeID%3a40', 'timeID%3a39', 'timeID%3a37']; 

        // select countries
        for(var c in countries) {
            document.getElementById(countries[c]).setAttribute('checked', true);
        }
        // select years
        for(var y in years) {
            document.getElementById(years[y]).setAttribute('checked', true);
        }
        // select variants
        document.getElementById('varID%3a2').setAttribute('checked', true); // medium
        // click button
        document.getElementById('ctl00_main_filters_anchorApplyBottom').click(); 
    });

    console.log('\nWaiting 1.5 seconds...');    
   await timeout(1500);

   // get only the table contents
    var result = await page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.querySelectorAll('.DataContainer table')[0].outerHTML; 
    });
    console.log('\n\nRESULT:', result);

    elaborateResult(result);

    await instance.exit();
};

function elaborateResult(res) {
    var el = document.createElement('html'); // ** ERROR HERE **
    el.innerHTML = result;
    console.log('\n\nTD ELEMENTS:', el.getElementsByTagName('td'));
    //var obj = utilFunc.createJsonObjectPop(year, country, population);
    //console.log(obj);
}
```

There are two errors:

1. `result` contains only the values that are on the first page of the results, but with the selections made you get 22 pages of results and I don't understand how I can get all the values that interest me and link them in the variable `result`.
2. assuming to have solved the problem in point (1), now I should elaborate the results obtained and create an object like this:

`var date = [{year: 2018, country: 'Albania', population: 2934.363}, {year: 2017, country: 'Albania', population: 2930.187}, ..., {year: 1980, country: 'United Kingdom ', population: 56265.475}]`

This is what the `elaborateResult(res)` function should do (of course, the function is not complete, I have to finish it but I get an error at the first line), but I get the error:

> ReferenceError: document is not defined

So I changed my strategy and I tried not to use `Phantom` but a normal `request`:

```
var options = {
    uri: 'http://data.un.org/Handlers/DataHandler.ashx?Service=query&Anchor=variableID%3a12&Applied=crID%3a8&crID%3a40;timeID%3a79&DataMartId=PopDiv&UserQuery=population&c=2,4,6,7&s=_crEngNameOrderBy:asc,_timeEngNameOrderBy:desc,_varEngNameOrderBy:asc&RequestId=302',
    transform: function(body) {
        return cheerio.load(body);
    }
};

methods.download = async function(req, res) {
    request(options)
    .then(function($) {
        console.log('\n\nTHEN: ', $);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Error', err.stack());
    });
}
```

If I run this code I get:

```
THEN:  function (selector, context, r, opts) {
    if (!(this instanceof initialize)) {
      return new initialize(selector, context, r, opts);
    }
    opts = _.defaults(opts || {}, options);
    return Cheerio.call(this, selector, context, r || root, opts);
  }
```

In this case I have other problems.

1. I don't know how to build the url.
   In the example above I chose Albania (`crID% 3a8`) and Austria (`crID% 3a40`) and 2015 as year (`timeID% 3a79`).
   Yet if I go to the link just built, I get as a result the data on Albania from 2100 to 2095.
2. I don't know how to select the years or how to select variants or how to change pages.

I feel a bit stupid but I can't get what I want... I'm stuck.
Help would be very welcome!

Comment: You should create a new question for this **Edit 1**, because now you want to parse the HTML table and it is a different issue. But the initial problem — getting those data — was solved with my answer and I would appreciate you honoring my time and accepting the answer.

Comment: @Vaviloff You are right. Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your script that prevent successful scrape.

**To check a checkbox**, you don't set its value again (it's already set in HTML!), you set its `checked` attribute to *true*:

```
document.getElementById('crID%3a250').setAttribute("checked", true); // France
```

**The button that submits the form** is a hyperlink `<a>` which doesn't have a `submit` method, it should be clicked (it even has `onClick` function in the code)

```
 document.getElementById('ctl00_main_filters_anchorApplyBottom').click(); // submit the form
```

**The search request ** is sent through ajax and takes time to complete, so your script should wait for at least a second vefore trying to fetch the data. I'll show how to wait in the full working code below.

**Next**, you may get only the table data, no need to sip through all th HTML:

```
var result = await page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.querySelectorAll('.DataContainer table')[0].outerHTML; 
});
```

Here's a bit trimmed down version of you script with issues corrected:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

var url = 'http://data.un.org/Data.aspx?q=population&d=PopDiv&f=variableID%3A12';

// A promise to wait for n of milliseconds
const timeout = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

(async function(req, res) {
    const instance = await phantom.create();
    const page = await instance.createPage();

    await page.on('onResourceRequested', function(requestData) {
        console.info('Requesting', requestData.url);
    });
    await page.on('onConsoleMessage', function(msg) {
        console.info(msg);
    });

    const status = await page.open(url);
    await console.log('STATUS:', status);

    // submit
    await page.evaluate(function() {
        document.getElementById('crID%3a250').setAttribute("checked", true); // France
        document.getElementById('timeID%3a79').setAttribute("checked", true); // 2015
        document.getElementById('varID%3a2').setAttribute("checked", true); // Medium
        document.getElementById('ctl00_main_filters_anchorApplyBottom').click(); // click submit button
    });

    console.log('Waiting 1.5 seconds..');    
    await timeout(1500);

    // Get only the table contents
    var result = await page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.querySelectorAll('.DataContainer table')[0].outerHTML; 
    });
    await console.log('RESULT:', result);

    await instance.exit();
})();
```

---

The last but not the least observation is that you could simply try to replay an ajax request made by the form and find out that [the URL of search request](http://data.un.org/Handlers/DataHandler.ashx?Service=query&Anchor=variableID%3a12&Applied=crID%3a250;timeID%3a79;varID%3a2&DataMartId=PopDiv&UserQuery=population&c=2,4,6,7&s=_crEngNameOrderBy:asc,_timeEngNameOrderBy:desc,_varEngNameOrderBy:asc&RequestId=873) works quite well on its own, when just opened in another tab:

[image: search result is HTML]

You don't even need a headless browser to get it, just cUrl/requests and process. It happens with sites a lot, so it's useful to check network tab in your browser devtools before scraping.

**Update**

And if there are so many results that they are scattered over several pages, there is one more parameter to be used in request: `Page`:

> data.un.org/Handlers/DataHandler.ashx?Service=page&**Page=3**&DataFilter=variableID:12&DataMartId=PopDiv&UserQuery=population&c=2,4,6,7&s=_crEngNameOrderBy:asc,_timeEngNameOrderBy:desc,_varEngNameOrderBy:asc&RequestId=461

Comment: Thank you! Could you be more specific about how to use the second proposed solution? That is the one without using Phantom. Sorry but it's the first time I do web scraping so I have a lot of difficulties. I also saw that you used `(async function(req, res) {` instead of `methods.download = async function(req, res) {`. I used `methods.download = async function(req, res) {` because I need to do this process when I call a certain method (the `download()` function). But I do not think there are problems if I do `methods.download = async function(req, res) {`, no?

Comment: Furthermore there is also another problem. The table is split across multiple pages, so `result` contains only the first page of data, not the complete data..

Comment: Updated the answer to address your latest comment, but I gotta say you could have figured this one youself :) the initial phantom/node script was quite good!

Comment: `How to use second proposed solution` Just get the table directly from [URL](http://data.un.org/Handlers/DataHandler.ashx?Service=query&Anchor=variableID%3a12&Applied=crID%3a903;timeID%3a180&DataMartId=PopDiv&UserQuery=population&c=2,4,6,7&s=_crEngNameOrderBy:asc,_timeEngNameOrderBy:desc,_varEngNameOrderBy:asc&RequestId=302) and scrape your data from there. What's you server-side language of choice?

Comment: `instead of methods.download` Just simplified a code sample a little. Of course you do the same inside of a module, the initial way your script was written.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I modified the main message, I hope you can help me.

Comment: You shouldn't change questions. Your initial issue is solve, if you've got have another problem, feel free to create a new question (you're allowed to create as many of them as you want).