# Web scraping using Node.js and request

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

I want to do web scraping of [this site](http://data.un.org/Data.aspx?q=population&d=PopDiv&f=variableID%3A12).
I have seen that the APIs are available but, as suggested by *duraid* in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49705059/download-data-from-undata-of-onu/49709369#49709369), it is not advisable to use them.

So I tried to use `Node.js` and [`Phantom.js`](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj0_P6146jaAhXsKsAKHfhCAcMQFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphantomjs.org%2F&usg=AOvVaw06wt7iUuvR9VtVXUxcnV34) with [`Phantom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom) . 
But the user [*Vaviloff* pointed out to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49710545/scrape-information-with-form-submit-using-phantom/49715409?noredirect=1#comment86465461_49715409) that a headless browser is not necessary because it is sufficient to use the URL of search request.

So I changed my strategy and I tried not to use `Phantom` but a normal `request`:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request-promise');

var options = {
    uri: 'http://data.un.org/Handlers/DataHandler.ashx?Service=query&Anchor=variableID%3a12&Applied=crID%3a8&crID%3a40;timeID%3a79&DataMartId=PopDiv&UserQuery=population&c=2,4,6,7&s=_crEngNameOrderBy:asc,_timeEngNameOrderBy:desc,_varEngNameOrderBy:asc&RequestId=302',
    transform: function(body) {
        return cheerio.load(body);
    }
};

methods.download = async function(req, res) {
    request(options)
    .then(function($) {
        console.log('\n\nTHEN: ', $);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Error', err.stack());
    });
}
```

If I run this code I get:

```
THEN:  function (selector, context, r, opts) {
    if (!(this instanceof initialize)) {
      return new initialize(selector, context, r, opts);
    }
    opts = _.defaults(opts || {}, options);
    return Cheerio.call(this, selector, context, r || root, opts);
  }
```

In this case I have other problems.

1. I don't know how to build the url.
   In the example above I chose Albania (`crID% 3a8`) and Austria (`crID% 3a40`) and 2015 as year (`timeID% 3a79`).
   Yet if I go to the link just built, I get as a result the data on Albania from 2100 to 2095.
2. I don't know how to select the years or how to select variants or how to change pages.

I'm interested in information about:

```
var countries = {
    'Albania': 'crID%3a8',
    'Austria': 'crID%3a40',
    'Belgium': 'crID%3a56',
    'Bulgaria': 'crID%3a100',
    'Croatia': 'crID%3a191',
    'Cyprus': 'crID%3a196',
    'Denmark': 'crID%3a208',
    'Estonia': 'crID%3a233',
    'Finland': 'crID%3a246',
    'France': 'crID%3a250',
    'Germany': 'crID%3a276',
    'Greece': 'crID%3a300',
    'Iceland': 'crID%3a352',
    'Ireland': 'crID%3a372',
    'Italy': 'crID%3a380',
    'Latvia': 'crID%3a428',
    'Netherlands': 'crID%3a528',
    'Norway': 'crID%3a578',
    'Poland': 'crID%3a616',
    'Portugal': 'crID%3a620',
    'Romania': 'crID%3a642',
    'Slovakia': 'crID%3a703',
    'Slovenia': 'crID%3a705',
    'Spain': 'crID%3a724',
    'Sweden': 'crID%3a752',
    'Switzerland': 'crID%3a756',
    'United Kingdom': 'crID%3a826'
};
// 2018 - 1980
var years = ['timeID%3a83', 'timeID%3a82', 'timeID%3a81', 'timeID%3a79', 'timeID%3a78', 'timeID%3a77', 'timeID%3a76', 'timeID%3a75', 'timeID%3a73', 'timeID%3a72', 'timeID%3a71', 'timeID%3a70', 'timeID%3a69', 'timeID%3a67', 'timeID%3a66', 'timeID%3a65', 'timeID%3a64', 'timeID%3a63', 'timeID%3a61', 'timeID%3a60', 'timeID%3a59', 'timeID%3a58', 'timeID%3a57', 'timeID%3a55', 'timeID%3a54', 'timeID%3a53', 'timeID%3a52', 'timeID%3a51', 'timeID%3a49', 'timeID%3a48', 'timeID%3a47', 'timeID%3a46', 'timeID%3a45', 'timeID%3a43', 'timeID%3a42', 'timeID%3a41', 'timeID%3a40', 'timeID%3a39', 'timeID%3a37']; 
// medium
var variants = 'varID%3a2';
```

*Only for completeness*: once the data is selected, I need to create an object like this:

`var date = [{year: 2018, country: 'Albania', population: 2934.363}, {year: 2017, country: 'Albania', population: 2930.187}, ..., {year: 1980, country: 'United Kingdom ', population: 56265.475}]`

So I created a function like that:

```
methods.createJsonObjectPop = function(year, country, population) {
    return {
        year: year, 
        country: country, 
        population: population
    };
}
```

Any advice would be of great help to me!

---

## EDIT 1

**The content is divided into pages. How can we get all the data? By opening all the pages and merging the data maybe?**
This was obvious.
If *X* is the number of pages, I suppose I have to do different *X* requests.

**And how does the site know which page is requested?**
I think thanks to the url but I'm not sure (like `http://...Page=3...`).

I imagine this pseudocode:

```
var basicUrl = 'http://data.un.org/Handlers/DataHandler.ashx?Service=query&Anchor=variableID%3a12&Applied=crID%3a8;crID%3a40;crID%3a56;crID%3a100;crID%3a191;crID%3a196;crID%3a208;crID%3a233;crID%3a246;crID%3a250;crID%3a276;crID%3a300;crID%3a352;crID%3a372;crID%3a380;crID%3a428;crID%3a528;crID%3a578;crID%3a616;crID%3a620;crID%3a642;crID%3a703;crID%3a705;crID%3a724;crID%3a752;crID%3a756;crID%3a826;timeID%3a83;timeID%3a82;timeID%3a81;timeID%3a79;timeID%3a78;timeID%3a77;timeID%3a76;timeID%3a75;timeID%3a73;timeID%3a72;timeID%3a71;timeID%3a70;timeID%3a69;timeID%3a67;timeID%3a66;timeID%3a65;timeID%3a64;timeID%3a63;timeID%3a61;timeID%3a60;timeID%3a59;timeID%3a58;timeID%3a57;timeID%3a55;timeID%3a54;timeID%3a53;timeID%3a52;timeID%3a51;timeID%3a49;timeID%3a48;timeID%3a47;timeID%3a46;timeID%3a45;timeID%3a43;timeID%3a42;timeID%3a41;timeID%3a40;timeID%3a39;timeID%3a37;varID%3a2&DataMartId=PopDiv&UserQuery=population&c=2,4,6,7&s=_crEngNameOrderBy:asc,_timeEngNameOrderBy:desc,_varEngNameOrderBy:asc&RequestId=531';
let promises = [];
let allData = [];

var options = {
    uri: url,
    transform: function(body) {
        return cheerio.load(body);
    }
};

methods.download = async function(req, res) {
    for(var i = 0; i < X; i++) {
        var url = basicUrl + '&Page=' + i;
        let res = await request(options, url);
        let data = elaborateData(res);
        allData.push(data);
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
}

function elaborateData(res) {
    var el = document.createElement('html');
    // use javascript or jQuery to get data like:
    // var year = getElementByTag(...);
    // var country = getElementByTag(...);
    // var population = getElementByTag(...);
    return createJsonObjectPop(year, country, population);
}
```

---

## EDIT 2

```
var basicUrl = 'http://data.un.org/Handlers/DataHandler.ashx?Service=query&Anchor=variableID%3a12&Applied=crID%3a8;crID%3a40;crID%3a56;crID%3a100;crID%3a191;crID%3a196;crID%3a208;crID%3a233;crID%3a246;crID%3a250;crID%3a276;crID%3a300;crID%3a352;crID%3a372;crID%3a380;crID%3a428;crID%3a528;crID%3a578;crID%3a616;crID%3a620;crID%3a642;crID%3a703;crID%3a705;crID%3a724;crID%3a752;crID%3a756;crID%3a826;timeID%3a83;timeID%3a82;timeID%3a81;timeID%3a79;timeID%3a78;timeID%3a77;timeID%3a76;timeID%3a75;timeID%3a73;timeID%3a72;timeID%3a71;timeID%3a70;timeID%3a69;timeID%3a67;timeID%3a66;timeID%3a65;timeID%3a64;timeID%3a63;timeID%3a61;timeID%3a60;timeID%3a59;timeID%3a58;timeID%3a57;timeID%3a55;timeID%3a54;timeID%3a53;timeID%3a52;timeID%3a51;timeID%3a49;timeID%3a48;timeID%3a47;timeID%3a46;timeID%3a45;timeID%3a43;timeID%3a42;timeID%3a41;timeID%3a40;timeID%3a39;timeID%3a37;varID%3a2&DataMartId=PopDiv&UserQuery=population&c=2,4,6,7&s=_crEngNameOrderBy:asc,_timeEngNameOrderBy:desc,_varEngNameOrderBy:asc&RequestId=531';
let promises = [];
let allData = [];
var pages = 22; // data are splitting in 22 pages

methods.download = async function(req, res) {
    for(var i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
        var url = basicUrl + '&Page=' + i;

        var options = {
            uri: url,
            transform: function(html) {
                return cheerio.load(html);
            }
        };

        let res = await request(options)
        .then(function($) {
            return $;
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('Error', err.stack());
        });

        console.log('\n\nRES:', res);
        let data = elaborateData(res);
        allData.push(data);
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
}

function elaborateData($) {
    $('.td').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
    // use javascript or jQuery to get data like:
    // var year = getElementByTag(...);
    // var country = getElementByTag(...);
    // var population = getElementByTag(...);
    //return createJsonObjectPop(year, country, population);
}
```

If I run this code, I get:

```
RES: function (selector, context, r, opts) {
    if (!(this instanceof initialize)) {
      return new initialize(selector, context, r, opts);
    }
    opts = _.defaults(opts || {}, options);
    return Cheerio.call(this, selector, context, r || root, opts);
  }
```

## EDIT 3

```
var cheerioTableparser = require('cheerio-tableparser');

methods.download = async function(req, res) {
    for(var i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
        var url = basicUrl + '&Page=' + i; // DOESN'T WORK

        var options = {
            uri: url,
            transform: function(html) {
                return cheerio.load(html);
            }
        };

        let res = await request(options)
        .then(function($) {
            return $;
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('Error', err.stack());
        });

        //console.log('\n\nRES:', res);
        let data = elaborateData(res);
        allData.push(data);
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
}

function elaborateData($) {
    cheerioTableparser($);
    var data = $('table').parsetable(true, true, true);

    var countries = data[0];
    var years = data[1];
    var variants = data[2];
    var values = data[3];
    console.log('\ncountries:', countries);
    console.log('\nyears:', years);
    console.log('\nvariants:', variants);
    console.log('\nvalues:', values);

    // use javascript or jQuery to get data like:
    // var year = getElementByTag(...);
    // var country = getElementByTag(...);
    // var population = getElementByTag(...);
    //return createJsonObjectPop(year, country, population);
}
```

I get:

```
countries: [ 'Country or Area',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Albania',
  'Austria',
  'Austria',
  'Austria',
  'Austria',
  'Austria',
  'Austria',
  'Austria',
  'Austria',
  'Austria',
  'Austria',
  'Austria' ]

years: [ 'Year(s)',
  '2018',
  '2017',
  '2016',
  '2015',
  '2014',
  '2013',
  '2012',
  '2011',
  '2010',
  '2009',
  '2008',
  '2007',
  '2006',
  '2005',
  '2004',
  '2003',
  '2002',
  '2001',
  '2000',
  '1999',
  '1998',
  '1997',
  '1996',
  '1995',
  '1994',
  '1993',
  '1992',
  '1991',
  '1990',
  '1989',
  '1988',
  '1987',
  '1986',
  '1985',
  '1984',
  '1983',
  '1982',
  '1981',
  '1980',
  '2018',
  '2017',
  '2016',
  '2015',
  '2014',
  '2013',
  '2012',
  '2011',
  '2010',
  '2009',
  '2008' ]

variants: [ 'Variant',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium',
  'Medium' ]

values: [ 'Value',
  '2934.363',
  '2930.187',
  '2926.348',
  '2923.352',
  '2920.775',
  '2918.978',
  '2920.039',
  '2926.659',
  '2940.525',
  '2962.635',
  '2991.651',
  '3023.907',
  '3054.331',
  '3079.179',
  '3097.747',
  '3111.005',
  '3119.029',
  '3122.408',
  '3121.970',
  '3115.576',
  '3103.759',
  '3093.041',
  '3092.228',
  '3106.736',
  '3140.595',
  '3189.583',
  '3240.587',
  '3275.431',
  '3281.454',
  '3253.656',
  '3197.067',
  '3121.336',
  '3041.007',
  '2966.798',
  '2901.592',
  '2842.624',
  '2788.314',
  '2735.329',
  '2681.239',
  '8751.820',
  '8735.453',
  '8712.137',
  '8678.657',
  '8633.220',
  '8577.782',
  '8517.548',
  '8459.864',
  '8409.949',
  '8370.038',
  '8338.453' ]
```

It works, only I can only get the data from the first page.

Comment: its available to download, why you want to scrape it?
Use its csv format to create your object

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan Because I'd like to create an app that automatically downloads data, and I'd rather not have read file from filesystem

Comment: But for that you are using a resource and scraping it,
while You can have it scraped after downloading the CSV within your app..

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan I prefer not to download anything

Comment: You don't have to download. its content stream that you can parse without saving anything locally..
and everything remains within app, just like the request you are making for page with data.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan Ah. Can you post some example code to do that?

Comment: oops they have a zip file, you have to go this way now... :(

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan Thanks anyway!

Comment: I can tell You code, but Let me get free.. Working on something else right now bro

Comment: `Yet if I go to the link just built` Don't build the link manually! Open devtools in Google Chrome, select Network tab, click "XHR" filter: https://i.imgur.com/g500gE4.png then check all the boxes you need and hit "apply filters". You'll see the request you need, right-click and copy its URL.

Comment: @Vaviloff Aaah. I didn't understand that it was done this way! Ok, now I have the correct url but I always have the problem of the fact that the content is divided into pages and I don't know where is the html that interests me..

Comment: Let's think. The content is divided into pages. How can we get all the data? By opening all the pages and merging the data maybe? And how does the site know which page is requested?

Comment: @Vaviloff I tried to answer these questions in the main message I edited.

Comment: Great, almost there! Now to inspect what actually is returned from every request and how to better process it. A quick note though: in `elaborateData`'s  `document.createElement` what is `document`? Where did it come from?

Comment: @Vaviloff I removed `document` and I modified the code a bit.. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Now you've got another issue that can be stated as "how to parse table cells with Cheerio". But before creating another question I'd suggest trawling Google for some time, as it is rather a simple problem.

Comment: @Vaviloff You're right, however, I still have the problem that I can only get the first page of results. This code doesn't work: `var url = basicUrl + '&Page=' + i;`

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you've it's the correct URL you use? Where does that `Page` parameter come from? Is it a guess? Why not `pageNum` ?

Comment: @Vaviloff I solved. The url was wrong. Thank you very much. If you want to post an answer, I accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay very close attention to all the request that scraped sites make.

if you whatch your target site for ajax requests to pages other than 1, you'll see that the initial URL

> http://data.un.org/Handlers/DataHandler.ashx?Service=query&Anchor=variableID%3a12&Applied=crID%3a8&crID%3a40;timeID%3a79&DataMartId=PopDiv&UserQuery=population&c=2,4,6,7&s=_crEngNameOrderBy:asc,_timeEngNameOrderBy:desc,_varEngNameOrderBy:asc&RequestId=302

is replaced with another:

> http://data.un.org/Handlers/DataHandler.ashx?Service=page&Page=2&DataFilter=variableID%3a12%3btimeID%3a178%2c179&DataMartId=PopDiv&UserQuery=population&c=2,4,6,7&s=_crEngNameOrderBy:asc,_timeEngNameOrderBy:desc,_varEngNameOrderBy:asc&RequestId=361

i.e. `Service=query` is replaced with `Service=page` which also accepts page number `Page=N`.

You can monitor such requests in all modern browsers, although currently I prefger Google Chrome because its devtools are the fastest in my experience.

So in Google Chrome press F12 or CTRL + I then click on "Network" tab, then click on "XHR" filter. That will show you all the new ajax requests made by the site.

[image: Turn on AJAX requests monitor]